# error_expected_primary expression before in. In functions

Tags: c++

Here is my code. I try to fix it and I always obtain the same error: expected primary expression before 'int'.

in line 47, 55, 63, 80, 86.

And I've already tried this program in small pieces before and it works. It doesn't marked that error.

`
    #include

```
using namespace std;


int add (int a, int b)
{
int r;
r=a+b;
return (r);
}


int ssub (int a, int b)
{
int r;
r=a-b;
return (r);
}


int mult(int a, int b)
{
int r;
r=a*b;
return (r);
}


int menu(int a, int b){

int r;
char x;
cout <<"What do you want to do: \na.Adding \n s. Substract \n m. Multiply. \n. e. Exit"<<endl;
cin>>x;

switch (x){
case 'a':
cout << "Give a value for a"<<endl;
cin>>a;
cout <<"Give a value for b"<<endl;
cin>>b;
add (int a, int b); //aquí y en otras líneas me sale: expected primary expression before int.
break;

case 's':
cout << "Give a value for a"<<endl;
cin>>a;
cout <<"Give a value for b"<<endl;
cin>>b;
ssub (int a, int b);
break;

case 'm':
cout << "Give a value for a"<<endl;
cin>>a;
cout <<"Give a value for b"<<endl;
cin>>b;
mult (int a, int b);
break;

case 'e':
x='e';
break;

default:
cout<<"Wrong choice. Run the program again and choose another letter"<<endl;
break;
}

return r;

}

cout<<"The result is  " << menu (int a, int b)<<endl;


int main()
{

menu (int a, int b);

return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: Which lines are 47, 55, 63, 80, and 86?  And who stole your tab key?

Answer (score 0):

Change main to look like this:

```
int main()
{
    menu();

    return 0;
}
```

---

Change `menu` to look like this:

```
void menu() {
    int a;
    int b;
    // remove int r; and return r; from menu function
    // then everything else stays the same
```

---

In your `switch` statement, change this:

```
add (int a, int b);
```

To this:

```
add(a,b);
```

And do the same in every other place where you've included `int` in your function calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
add (int a, int b);
```

You can't have the `int` tokens here - you want to use the values of existing variables `a` and `b`, not declare them.  They were already declared in the function introduction `int menu(int a, int b)`.

You need just:

```
add(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call your functions you should just use the variable names you're passing into it without adding it's type before it:

...

```
cout <<"Give a value for b"<<endl;
cin>>b;
add (int a, int b); //aquí y en otras líneas me sale: expected primary expression before int.
break;
```

...

Should be:
...

```
cout <<"Give a value for b"<<endl;
cin>>b;
add (a, b); //aquí y en otras líneas me sale: expected primary expression before int.
break;
```

...

By adding the int keywords before a and b I think you might be redeclaring those variables.